# How to combine jquery.validate plugin with jquery.serialize()

Tags: jquery, html, validation, serialization

I have tried to validate the form using the [jquery.validate](http://jzaefferer.github.com/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.js) plugin before being executed by ajax, but it failed because the ajax submit is working when using validate function.

Here is my form:

```
<form>
 <p><label for="cname">Name</label><em>*</em><input id="cname" name="name" size="25" class="required" minlength="2" /></p>
   <p><label for="cemail">E-Mail</label><em>*</em><input id="cemail" name="email" size="25"  class="required email" /></p>
   <p><label for="curl">URL</label><em></em><input id="curl" name="url" size="25"  class="url" value="" /></p>
   <p><label for="ccomment">Your comment</label><em>*</em><textarea id="ccomment" name="comment" cols="22"  class="required"></textarea></p>
   <p><input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/></p>
 </form>
```

And my jquery code:

```
$('form').validate();
$('form').submit(function() {
  alert($(this).serialize());
  return false;
});
```

here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ongisnade/tzFzR/

How to make form validate before ajax submited?

Comment: Use `.valid()` to check before using `.serialize()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Use `.valid()` to check before using `.serialize()`.

```
// Initialize
$('form').validate();

// Bind
$('form').submit(function() {
    if($('form').valid())
        alert($(this).serialize());
    else
        alert("Invalid");
    return false;
});​
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eHD4g/

#### Or as [Sparky672](https://stackoverflow.com/users/594235/sparky672) said, use the `submitHandler` attribute:

```
$('form').validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        alert($('form').serialize());
        return false;
    }
});
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eHD4g/2/

Comment: Is there any particular advantage to this over just putting `serialize` inside the `.validate()` plugin's built-in submit handler?  http://jsfiddle.net/eHD4g/1/

Comment: You are changing the `.validate()` plugin, but if you wanna update to a newer version, it would be difficult. Makes sense?

Comment: @Sparky672 This is also right! With your knowledge, am updating the answer. `:)` My mistake, I thought you wanna modify the plugin. Sorry. `:)`

Comment: Check my updated fiddle, I had to modify the selector, but same solution.

Comment: I've a collection of SO answers about this `submitHandler`.  Sometimes funny things happen when you try to bind the `submit` externally rather than using the plugin's own internal handler.  I never chance it.

Comment: Upvote for the 2nd form of the answer, the first form is ... not the way you should use the validate plugin